# c make file compilation error

Tags: c

```
Syntax error at line 72, column 26, file /usr/include/gconv.h:
Error at line 72, column 26 in file /usr/include/gconv.h
unsigned char **, size_t *, int, int);
.........................1
PCC-S-02201, Encountered the symbol "size_t" when expecting one of the following
:

... auto, char, const, double, enum, float, int, long,
ulong_varchar, OCIBFileLocator OCIBlobLocator,
OCIClobLocator, OCIDateTime, OCIExtProcContext, OCIInterval,
OCIRowid, OCIDate, OCINumber, OCIRaw, OCIString, register,
short, signed, sql_context, sql_cursor, static, struct,
union, unsigned, utext, uvarchar, varchar, void, volatile,
a typedef name, exec oracle, exec oracle begin, exec,
exec sql, exec sql begin, exec sql type, exec sql var,
The symbol "enum," was substituted for "size_t" to continue.

Syntax error at line 88, column 7, file /usr/include/gconv.h:
Error at line 88, column 7 in file /usr/include/gconv.h
size_t *);
......1
PCC-S-02201, Encountered the symbol "size_t" when expecting one of the following
:

... auto, char, const, double, enum, float, int, long,
ulong_varchar, OCIBFileLocator OCIBlobLocator,
OCIClobLocator, OCIDateTime, OCIExtProcContext, OCIInterval,
OCIRowid, OCIDate, OCINumber, OCIRaw, OCIString, register,
short, signed, sql_context, sql_cursor, static, struct,
union, unsigned, utext, uvarchar, varchar, void, volatile,
a typedef name, exec oracle, exec oracle begin, exec,
exec sql, exec sql begin, exec sql type, exec sql var,
The symbol "enum," was substituted for "size_t" to continue.

Syntax error at line 97, column 6, file /usr/include/gconv.h:
Error at line 97, column 6 in file /usr/include/gconv.h
size_t *);
.....1
PCC-S-02201, Encountered the symbol "size_t" when expecting one of the following
:

... auto, char, const, double, enum, float, int, long,
ulong_varchar, OCIBFileLocator OCIBlobLocator,
OCIClobLocator, OCIDateTime, OCIExtProcContext, OCIInterval,
OCIRowid, OCIDate, OCINumber, OCIRaw, OCIString, register,
short, signed, sql_context, sql_cursor, static, struct,
union, unsigned, utext, uvarchar, varchar, void, volatile,
a typedef name, exec oracle, exec oracle begin, exec,
exec sql, exec sql begin, exec sql type, exec sql var,
The symbol "enum," was substituted for "size_t" to continue.

Syntax error at line 106, column 3, file /usr/include/gconv.h:
Error at line 106, column 3 in file /usr/include/gconv.h
__gconv_trans_fct __trans_fct;
..1
PCC-S-02201, Encountered the symbol "__gconv_trans_fct" when expecting one of th
e following:

char, const, double, enum, float, int, long, ulong_varchar,
OCIBFileLocator OCIBlobLocator, OCIClobLocator, OCIDateTime,
OCIExtProcContext, OCIInterval, OCIRowid, OCIDate, OCINumber,
OCIRaw, OCIString, short, signed, sql_context, sql_cursor,
struct, union, unsigned, utext, uvarchar, varchar, void,
volatile, a typedef name,

Error at line 53, column 11 in file /usr/include/libio.h
# include <stdarg.h>
..........1
```

Comment: That is a very lovely error. Can you give us more information on how you reached it, the tool chain you are using, environment / OS and other trivial bits of information that the rest of us might consider useful?

Comment: @Tim: This is about on par with their other questions.

Comment: I'm voting to close this as not a real question. To the OP, next time, please provide more information and monitor your question after asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like Pro*C error message.

Check `sys_include` parameter in your `$ORACLE_HOME/precomp/admin/pcscfg.cfg` file (or whichever config file is used by `proc` - `proc` tells it on startup). This parameter must include correct path to system headers.

**EDIT** BTW while you are on this file, it makes sense to change value of `PARSE` parameter to `PARTIAL` (don't remember what was default) - it will tell Pro*C to be more relaxed about C syntax.

Comment: I already edit $ORACLE_HOME/precomp/admin/pcscfg.cfg  file & resolve some error but unable to resolve these errors.The code written in c.

Comment: i got the solution.
sys_include=(/user/include,/user/include/linux) in pcscfg.cfg file.

Parse=none in your make file.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like at least one include file is missing where size_t is defined. Whichever that might be, on Linux look in `/usr/include` ... well, might be in `unistd.h`, so include that.

The other stuff might just result from the first error, hard to tell with the information provided here.

Comment: Cold. Very, very cold. Frozen.

Comment: @Tim Nothing to do with PCC because these are not compiler errors - they come from Oracle'e Pro*C preprocessor. People who have some experience with Pro*C will recognise such messages on the spot.